# mySQLi inserts script taking forever

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Here's basically what's stored inside my **PHP** script

```
$query = $db->query("
SELECT *
FROM `media`
WHERE `id` > '$last_id'
AND `accounts_used` != ''
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 100
");

foreach($query['results'] as $row) {
    $last_id = $row['id'];
    $accounts_used = explode(", ",$row['accounts_used']);
    $db->connect();
    foreach($accounts_used as $liked_account) {
        $account_id = str_replace(" ","",$liked_account);
        $media_id = $row['id'];
        $insert_array = array(
            "account_id" => $account_id,
            "media_id" => $media_id,
            "timesent" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        );
        $db->insert("media_likes", $insert_array);
    }
    $db->disconnect();
}
```

An example of the `$row['accounts_used']` is like so

```
61519, 65894, 63561, 61718, 63567, 66924, 66979, 66972, 66637, 66295, 66842, 64775, 51898, 64631, 65044, 67226, 67582, 66861, 51543, 61564, 65597, 66863
```

On average the `accounts_used` row contains around **1000/2000** unique ID's which are separated by commas, I want to explode based on the comma and insert each ID into another table.

`media_id` contains an integer value roughly around 5 digits long and `account_id` is about the same

This script is taking around 3 minutes to complete, any specific ways to improve such functionality? or a quicker way to do it?

Comment: "unique ID's which are separated by commas," arggggg normalise!

Comment: If you are inserting a lot of rows, you want to use a transaction.  What's happening is after each insert, it needs to update the indexes.  In a transaction, it'll only do that after its committed.  That should speed it up.

Comment: SELECT * is a real database killer.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things I can see that might help off the bat:

1 - you are opening and closing your db connection after each row of data you process (don't)

2 - you can use a prepared statement to have the mysql connection "pre-compile" your insert statement

3 - use a transaction around the inserts so your indexes only get updated once

Comment: Thank you so much, It now only took 6 seconds to complete using transactions and placing my connect/disconnect outside the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have a table with a lot of rows, so the problem is not in the way you insert itself but in optimization of the table.
If that's the case you could try changing the indexes and foreing keys, that might improve the speed.
Also you can try an in-line insert to see if it improves.